# Как сделать php (или другую программу) доступной для вызова из командной строки?

Tags: php

Как сделать php (или другую программу) доступной для вызова из командной строки?

Comment: Что-то не совсем понятно: как написать программу на PHP, чтобы она запускалась с командной строки или как запускать `executable file` самого PHP (да и про какой системы командую строку идет речь?)

Comment: Начнем с того, что PHP - это не программа, я язык  :)

Comment: Уточните операционную систему

Answer (score 2):

описывается скрипт например в таком файле myscript.php затем в консоле:

```
php myscript.php
```

если не винда, то можно сделать в начале в myscript.php такой код:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

и выставить права на исполнение, и он тоже будет исполняться.
под виндой тоже будет, но только в каком-нить шелле, например Bash

Comment: Не "если не винда", а "если unix-like". Бывают и другие ОС

Comment: Я как раз спрашиваю о том, как сделать так, чтобы php myscript.php запускался.
Сейчас пишет, что не в курсе что такое "php"

win7

Comment: надо добавить в системный PATH путь к пхп

Comment: @nMike - пропишите полный путь до `php.exe` типа `C:\Program Files\..\php.exe` (или где он установлен). Или пропишите путь до `php.exe` в `PATH` системы - тогда каждый раз не потребуется указывать полный путь. Это же элементарно...

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от ОС вам нужно написать соответствующий исполняемый файл.

Windows:

Должен быть .bat файл с примерно таким содержимым:

```
php /path/to/file.php
```

Но в этом случае путь к интерпретатору php (php.exe) должен быть прописан в PATH. Можете вместо "php" в bat файле указать полный путь к php.exe для запуска скрипта. Не знаю будет ли это работать в windows но в linux это точно работает и я не вижу причин почему это не будет работать под windows

Linux:

Должен быть .sh файл примерно с таким содержимым:

```
#!/bin/sh
php /path/to/file.php
```

Файл *.sh нужно будет сделать исполняемым командой chmod +x file.sh и положить в любое удобное для вас место.

Ну и ваш php файл соответственно нужно будет запускать через эти bat и sh файлы.

Comment: В виндах батник необязателен. Можно прописать ассоциацию расширения файла ".php" с интерпретатором php.exe (если склероз не изменяет). Ещё (также необходимо) в какой-то переменной добавить .php в список расширений исполняемых файлов.

Но, возможно, всё это не относится к cmd.exe, только к explorer'у. Проверить не могу.

Comment: В никсах тоже командный файл не нужен, достаточно в начало вставить #!/путь_к_интерпретатору и поставить x-бит файлу